# Is there an open source POSIX PSE51 compliant RTOS?

Tags: posix, open-source, rtos

IEEE Std 1003.13-2003 defines a set of POSIX profiles for real-time systems. PSE51 is one of these profiles. I'm studying about PSE51 and I think it would be very helpful if I had access to an implementation of an RTOS compliant with this profile. Looking at some code always makes things clearer than reading requirements and specifications.

I already did a research but just found proprietary implementations. Is there an open source implementation of an RTOS compliant with PSE51 or any other of the real-time profiles?

Answer (score 2):

A little late to answer, but please do check out Zephyr, an Open Source RTOS. It's 1.11 release is almost POSIX compliant, with the exception of support for File System APIs. It's 1.12 release is due in a week (June 2018), with full support for PSE52.

Find the code base here: https://github.com/zephyrproject-rtos/zephyr/

You can read more about the RTOS: https://www.zephyrproject.org/

Actually, Zephyr has evolved out of Wind River's Viper which derived from VxWorks earlier. It's been open sourced since 2016.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the PSE51-compliant RTOSs (e.g., eMCOS, PikeOS, Neutrino, VxWorks) are commercial products.

As far as I know, the only *open-source* RTOSs that are PSE51-compliant are:

- [MarteOS](https://marte.unican.es)
- [Shark](http://shark.sssup.it/) (fully compliant to PSE52)
- [RTEMS](https://www.rtems.org/) ([*almost*](https://docs.rtems.org/branches/master/posix-compliance.pdf) compliant to PSE51 + subsets of PSE52/53/54)

Answer (score 0):

I read a paper that say **RTLinux** is a small **POSIX 1003.13/PSE51-compatible** hard realtime operating system. Unfortunately in 2007 Wind River acquired the company that created RTLinux and made a commercial product with it. I don't know if Wind River's version of RTLinux is open source. I found a GIT repository for rt-linux [here](https://github.com/clrkwllms/rt-linux). But it is named rt-linux, not RTLinux. I'm not sure they are the same thing.